# Get current theme's default cursor color after it's changed

Tags: themes, cursor

How to get the current theme's default cursor color after it's modified by "set-cursor-color" of other functions that I defined?

I thought I was able to get the default color value by storing it in a variable earlier when "load-theme" is executed to switch to a theme.

Code:

```
  ;;; Define after-load-theme-hook
  (defvar after-load-theme-hook nil
    "Hook run after a color theme is loaded using `load-theme'.")
  (defadvice load-theme (after run-after-load-theme-hook activate)
    "Run `after-load-theme-hook'."
    (run-hooks 'after-load-theme-hook))

  ;;; Toggle read-only-mode & cursor color changed
  (defvar current-cursor-color nil)
  (defun get-current-cursor-color ()
    "Return current theme's cursor color in current frame"
    (face-attribute 'cursor :background nil 'custom-enabled-themes))
  (add-hook 'after-load-theme-hook (lambda ()
                     (setq current-cursor-color
                       (get-current-cursor-color))))
```

But no, when startup, the color will be "black". And after emacs' started up, when I load a theme as the current theme with "load-theme", the color will be set by (set-cursor-color "#*color*") in a function by me in various other hooks.

How can I get the default cursor color of the current theme?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: `set-cursor-color` "works by setting the ‘cursor-color’ frame parameter on the selected frame"; so `(frame-parameter nil 'cursor-color)`?  (That's not what you've asked for, but it looks like what you actually want?)

Comment: I tried to evaluate the application (frame-parameter nil 'cursor-color) in a buffer, but it still outputs colors based on modification of cursor color by (set-cursor-color), and it outputs error if I specify a theme for it(This one may be off-topic if the application can be used to get default color when load-theme is run, but as I tested, it couldn't.

Comment: The second-to-last paragraph of your question seemed (to me) to say that various code was calling `set-cursor-color` and you wanted something which would obtain the value that had been set in that way.  If you *don't* want that, then I misunderstood the question, so my comment isn't helpful.